# How to stop group chat creation when using FB.ui() with multiple people

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using the `FB.ui()` and I can't seem to debug this.
How can I send it to multiple people, but not create a group chat? Is there a parameter I can use to prevent it? Or a hack/trick I can use to stop it?

This is my code...

```
FB.ui({
    app_id: '',
    method: 'send',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1226220854077249/roles/test-users/'
});
```

I started adding participants in a later time, but it always creates a group chat. I have tried debugging this for two days now. How can I prevent group chats?

Comment: You can't. You can change the behavior.

Comment: So groups will always be created? Or is there a way to prevent it at all?

Comment: Yes groups will always be created. You can change that

Comment: Um... can? Or can't?

Comment: Sorry. Can't. But stackoverflow require me to write a lot

Comment: Okay. Thank you, but that in an answer and Ill accept it... even thought that's not what my company will want to hear.

Comment: You know anything about notification? Using the FB.api()?